# Not able to add new Remote Java Application for debugging in STS

Tags: debugging, weblogic, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to debug application deployed on weblogic server and for that I had followed following steps in STS

1) Run -> Debug Configuration -> Remote Java Application

but when I try to click on New then nothing is appearing on screen so ultimately I am not able to add my application for remote debugging in STS.

**STS verion is  3.7.2.RELEASE**

Comment: do you see anything showing up in the Error Log view? Maybe an exception is being thrown under the hood somewhere.

Comment: I can't see anything in  Error Log view

Comment: strange... can you try with a vanilla STS 3.9.7 installation (to double check)?

Comment: Ok will do that. also I was not able to add oracle web logic server in server in my sts few days before. I guess STS verion is 3.7.2.RELEASE is unstable version

Answer (score 0):

Maximise the tab, Don't search it in the search box. eventhough nothing happening debug configurations are created for me. You can see them under Remote Java Application drop down